# What tool can I use to cut wall studs straight?

Tags: wood, tools, studs

Is there a hand tool (not power) that can be used to facilitate straight (or angled) cutting of wall studs?

Something similar to [this Miter Box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IOXCNKK), but for larger/heavier woods, such as 2x4 or 2x6 wall studs.

Comment: Basic mitre boxes can actually be made with pieces of existing lumber, careful measurements, etc. Have you considered making such a box to use with your large manual saw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A handsaw, a square, and practice. While it seems common for folks starting out to reject this option, (practice seems to be out of style) it works. But you need to accept the idea that you'll actually have to make some practice cuts and get in the habit of noticing how the saw is cutting and learn to keep it on track.

A mitre box. You can make one from wood of whatever size you need.